# What underlies intlinprog in MATLAB?

Tags: integer-programming, gurobi, matlab

When a paper says they used the intlinprog in MATLAB to solve an integer program, what system actually does the solving?  I have seen documentation about Gurobi and MATLAB: does Gurobi always provide the solving for MATLAB or is that just one option?  What is the "default" solver?  Is it a high quality solver?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mention of **intlinprog**, without further specification, generally means the [`intlinprog`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/intlinprog.html) of the MATLAB Optimization Toolbox.

However, Gurobi also has a function called `intlinprog`, which mimics the interface of the  MATLAB Optimization Toolbox `intlinprog`, but which calls the Gurobi solver.  Similarly with Mosek.  CPLEX  has `cplexintlinprog`, which mimics the interface of the  MATLAB Optimization Toolbox `intlinprog`.  Gurobi, Mosek, and CPLEX also offer other interfaces in MATLAB offering additional functionality not available through the (cplex)intlinprog functions.

As to which winds up being the default, that depends on the order of entries in the MATLAB path. Many people don't even realize which solver they are using, and it wouldn't surprise me if there are published papers in which the author(s) used a different solver than what they thought.

Further compounding the potential confusion is that `intlinprog` might be called through an optimization modeling tool (language), in which case the user is further removed from the actual solver selection. Editorial note: yes of course you should look at the solver  output, at least during debugging and check out, but many people do not.

Comment: And is there any documentation on the quality of the intlinprog of the Toolbox?

Comment: There is the  Mittelmann MIPLIB2017 Benchmark data at http://plato.asu.edu/ftp/milp.html .Suffice it to say that the MATLAB Optimization Toolbox intlinprog is not generally the fastest MILP solver there is.